Copy data of a line in front of the data in the next line
Have data like
start {data}
target {ABC}
start {data2}
target {DEF}
target {GHI}
start {data3}
target {JKL}
....

I wish to move the {data} or {data2} which are after the keyword 'start' to their next lines i.e.
start {data}
target {data ABC}
start {data2}
target {data2 DEF}
target {data2 GHI}
start {data3}
target {data3 JKL}
....

I tried
sed '/^[[:space:]]*start*/{ N;s/[[:space:]]*target / /}'  

But this is not giving the desired output.

The line numbers were apparently not part of the actual data so I removed them. Going forward, please take care to provide exactly the data you want to operate on (or at the very least indicate if it has been marked up in some way).

It's important when posting questions to show truly representative values for your input, not just "dataN" everywhere, as the right answer will depend on what values the data can actually have, e.g. if it can contain {, }. &, \, or various other characters then it requires different solutions and possibly different tools than if it's just alpha-numeric. Same goes for ABC, etc. Please [edit] your question to show truly representative sample input and expected output so we can help you create a robust solution.

I see from your questions history that you never respond to comments asking for clarification of requirements and never accept any answers - you'll have more success getting help on this site if you participate in your questions by responding to comments, updating your question when asked for more info, and upvoting/accepting answers so people know what worked for you.

Using sed
$ sed -E '/start/{p;s/^[0-9]+\.start[^{]*\{([^}]*).*/\1 /;h;d};/target/{G;s/(\{)([^}]*})\n(.*)/\1\3\2/}' input_file
1.start {data}
2.target {data ABC}
3.start {data2}
4.target {data2 DEF}
5.target {data2 GHI}
6.start {data3}
7.target {data3 JKL}
..
..


If I understand the OP's question correctly, the line numbers are not actually part of the input.

Perhaps this answer should explain how the script actually solves the problem (and perhaps expand on why the OP's attempt did not work)?

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
start {data}
target {ABC}
start {data2}
target {DEF}
target {GHI}
start {data3}
target {JKL}
....

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="{"}/^start/{data=$2;sub(/}$/,"",data)}/^target/{$2=data " " $2}{print}' file.txt

gives output
start {data}
target {data ABC}
start {data2}
target {data2 DEF}
target {data2 GHI}
start {data3}
target {data3 JKL}
....

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that { is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS). If line starts with start I store what is after { in variable named data and use sub to remove trailing } from its' value. If line starts with target I prefix 2nd column ($2) with value stored in data variable and space. I print every line.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Your attempt would simply replace target with nothing. It contains no code to capture the actual value between the braces. But frankly, I would avoid sed for anything beyond single-line search and replace.
Here is a simple Awk solution.
awk '/^[[:space:]]*start / { split($0, tag, "[{}]") }
    !/^[[:space:]]*start / && tag[2] { sub(/\{/, "{" tag[2] " ") }
    1'

If the regex matches, split the line into the array tag on curly braces. Thus, the value in tag[2] is the value between the curlies.
Otherwise, replace the opening curly to add the stored value of tag[2] from the previous matching line.
The 1 is a shorthand to print all lines unconditionally.
Demo: https://ideone.com/ZRJACS

Using any awk:
$ awk '
    match($0,/{.*}/) {
        if ( /^start/ ) {
            data = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        }
        else {
            $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART) data OFS substr($0,RSTART+1)
        }
    }
    { print }
' file
start {data}
target {data ABC}
start {data2}
target {data2 DEF}
target {data2 GHI}
start {data3}
target {data3 JKL}

That will work robustly for any non-newline characters in your dataN or ABC, etc. strings as it only uses a regexp to match from the first { to the last } on every line and then uses literal string operations for the capture of what's between those chars in the start lines and insertion of those captured strings into the target lines.
If we change your first 2 input lines to contain some typically problematic chars/strings for these kinds of problems:
$ cat file
start {foo { & / \1 } # bar}
target {more { & / \1 } # chars}

then you can see the above script still works:
$ awk 'match($0,/{.*}/) { if ( /^start/ ) data=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2); else $0=substr($0,1,RSTART) data OFS substr($0,RSTART+1) } {print }' file
start {foo { & / \1 } # bar}
target {foo { & / \1 } # bar more { & / \1 } # chars}

while your other existing answers won't work because the example in your question only covers the simple sunny day case where there's just 1 { and 1 } on each line with the only characters between them alphanumeric and so the answers you're getting are designed to only handle that simple sunny-day input.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/^start/{h;b};G;s/^\(target {\)\(.*}.*\)\n.*{\(.*\)}/{\1\3 \2/;P;d' file

If a line begins start, make a copy and print as normal.
Otherwise, append the copy.
If a line begins target use pattern matching and back references to format the desired result.
What ever the result, print the first line in the pattern space and then delete it.
N.B. This will achieve the desired result with or without intervening lines.

If all lines have one of the two forms you show, the { to consider is the first encountered, and the } to consider is the last encountered, with any sed you can try:
sed '/^s/h;/^t/G;s/{\(.*}.*\)\n[^{]*\({.*\)}.*/\2 \1/' file

Explanations:

If the line begins with start we copy it to the hold space (h).
If the line begins with target we append to it a newline and the hold space (G).
We use the substitute command (s) to replace any {X}\nY{Z} with {Z X}.

Note: if there is only one {} pair per line and if the } is always the last character (no trailing spaces) we can simplify a bit:
sed '/^s/h;/^t/G;s/{\(.*}\)\n.*\({.*\)}/\2 \1/' file


$ awk -F'^start |[{}]' 'NF==4{d=$3} NF==3{sub($2,d" &")}1' file
start {data}
target {data ABC}
start {data2}
target {data2 DEF}
target {data2 GHI}
start {data3}
target {data3 JKL}

